# Table Text Running Outside Cell in iOS Mail

Tags: html, ios, css, html-email

I'm running into an issue where iOS Mail is increasing the text size, driving it outside the table cell. The table renders fine on desktop outlook/web mail, but fails on the Mail app. I've tried adding word wrap, but that didn't effect it at all. Is tehre a way to have either the text adjust to the box size or the box adjust to the text size?
Thanks!

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
      <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
      
        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        
        /* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
              word-wrap: break-word;        }
                
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        .counter {
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #73879C;
        border-left: 2pxsolid#ADB2B5;
        float: left;
       
        }
        .subcounter {
        font-size: 10px;font-weight: 300;
        border-left: 2pxsolid#ADB2B5;
        float: left;        
        } 

        }            
    </style>
    

            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center; height="75" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                        <br><br><div class="counter">99,999,999</div>
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%" style="">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% WoW 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% MoM 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% YoY 
                                </td>                        
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center; height="50" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                        <br><br><div class="counter">99,999,999</div>
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%" style="">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% WoW 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% MoM 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% YoY 
                                </td>                        
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center; height="50" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                        <br><br><div class="counter">99,999,999</div>
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%" style="">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% WoW 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% MoM 
                                </td>
                                <td style="padding: 5px 0; text-align: center; height="25" alt="alt_text" border="0" bgcolor="#dddddd" color: "#555555">
                                    <div class="subcounter">&#8964; 10% YoY 
                                </td>                        
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Looking at the code provided here, there seems to be a lot of issues with the inline styling on the tables. The style properties don't have a closing ", also color is sitting outside of the styling. I don't know if Zurb takes care of this when it's processed, but that could be causing rendering issues.

Also a lot of missing closing tags. Each of the subcounter divs and some closing td rather than tr

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove this in the table css:

```
table-layout: fixed !important;
```

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! I see at least part of the Cerberus email template in there (I maintain the project), so I will make a note of this in case it comes up again.

Comment: Thanks! The template is great btw! It helped me learn quite a lot as I tore into it to make some python modules to generate subsections.

Comment: Brilliant! Always nice to hear things like this!